# NotSerializableException in a ManagedBean with ViewScoped and Spring's services

Tags: serialization, jsf-2, spring-3

This is the ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean @ViewScoped public class DetailItem {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7647929779133437125L;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{itemServiceImpl}")
    private ItemService servItem;
```

This is the Service

```
@Service("itemServiceImpl") @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerLocal") public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("itemDaoImpl")
    private ItemDAO dao;
```

but when I try to access to the page that used 'DetailItem', I have the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
```

To fix that I do the servItem transient and obtain it from the applicationContext. But I understand that it is not the correct solution and I dont find any other. Which is the proper way to do that?

I don´t have the exception with sessionscoped or requestscoped.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a similar problem like [Serialization of ManagedProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141052/serialization-of-managedproperty/)

Does ItemService implement Serializable and are all members of ItemServiceImpl serializable themselves?